# knockout computed variables not showing

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following observables, but my totals don't update when I update my fields.

```
var formdata = ko.observable({
  a: 0,
  b: 0,
  c: 0,
  d: 0
});
var calcs = {
  calulatedValues: function() {
    this.total = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return formdata().a+formdata().b+formdata().c+formdata().d;
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(formdata, document.getElementByID("myForm"));
  ko.applyBindings(calcs, document.getElementByID("totals"));
});

<div id="totals">
  <div data-bind="with: calculatedValues">
    <div data-bind="total"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle to show what's happening](https://jsfiddle.net/sidkdbl07/ep8331qf/4/)

Comment: could you show your formdata html as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`with`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) binding creates a new binding context. So you should change it from a `function` to:

```
var calcs = {
  calulatedValues: {
    total: ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return formdata().a + formdata().b + formdata().c + formdata().d;
    });
  }
}
```

And you are not binding `total` properly. Change it to:

```
<div id="totals">
  <div data-bind="with: calculatedValues">
    <div data-bind="text: total"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It still won't work properly because there is a typo in `document.getElementByID("totals")`. It should be `Id`

```
ko.applyBindings(calcs, document.getElementById("totals"));
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/12kwq2p9/1/)

---

**Update**:

If you want the `computed` property to be triggered when `a`, `b`, `c` values get changed, then you should make them as `observable`s, not `formdata`.

```
var formdata = {
  a: ko.observable(0),
  b: ko.observable(1),
  c: ko.observable(0),
  d: ko.observable(0)
};
```

and change the `total` to:

```
total: ko.pureComputed(function() {
  // added the "Number" parsing, otherwise it concatenates numbers as strings
  return Number(formdata.a()) + Number(formdata.b()) + Number(formdata.c()) + Number(formdata.d());
})
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ep8331qf/6/)

Comment: looks like the poster has two view models bound to two different areas. wouldn't he need some sort of subscriber publisher set up to get the two view models to talk to each other?

Comment: @BryanDellinger Is that required? [In this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/12kwq2p9/6/) I'm updating `formdata`'s observable property and it's updating `total`.

Comment: but he has two viewmodels bound to two different areas.     ko.applyBindings(formdata, document.getElementByID("myForm"));
  ko.applyBindings(calcs, document.getElementByID("totals"));

Comment: my apologies adiga you are correct. I thought if you updated formdata in one view model it would not update in the other but it looks like it does.  https://jsfiddle.net/12kwq2p9/7/

Comment: @BryanDellinger no problem sir. I think you didn't see the fiddle I mentioned in the previous comment. I'm incrementing `formdata`'s observable every 2 seconds and it updates the computed property. https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/12kwq2p9/6/

Comment: Added a fiddle to show what's going on. https://jsfiddle.net/sidkdbl07/ep8331qf/4/

Comment: @sidkdbl07 You want the `computed` function to be triggered when `a`, `b`, `c` values get changed. So, make them as observables not `formdata`. https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/ep8331qf/6/

Comment: Works. Thank you @adiga